# Creation of an unwanted background process running Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, background-process, taskmanager

This is my first time posting a question to Stack Overflow.

I am developing a Word macro that, as part of its process, runs a macro in an Excel workbook.  The code in my Excel macro, as far as I can tell, runs as expected.  I believe my problem is occurring in my Word macro code, and the code snippets I show here are taken entirely from that source.

Here is the way in which the Word macro code is intended to work.  It code begins by determining if Excel is already open (the Excel application, not a workbook).  If the application is already open, my code makes a note and connects to it.  If not open, my code opens a new Excel application.   It then opens a new macro-enabled workbook and runs a designated macro embedded within it.  When the Excel macro terminates, control returns to my Word macro.  That macro first closes the Excel workbook (not the Excel application).  My code then tests whether the Excel application was already open when the Word macro started.  If yes, the Word macro does nothing; otherwise, it closes the Excel application.  The goal is to leave the user’s computer in the state it was in (at least regarding an open Excel application) before my Word macro ran.

My code is not running correctly for the following testing scenario.  I begin with no instance of an Excel application open (either as an App or as a background process); I verify this through the Task Manager.  I then run the following code procedure:

```
'initiate the Excel session
excelAlreadyRunning = True
'Determine if Excel is already running
On Error Resume Next
Set ExcelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 'if Excel is not open, this code line throws an error
                                                'is Excel is open, ExcelApp will point at it after
                                                'execution of this line of code
If Err.Number = APPLICATION_NOT_OPEN Then       'not already running - start it and make it visible
        excelAlreadyRunning = False
        Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        ExcelApp.Application.Visible = True
        Err.Clear
    Else
        ExcelApp.Application.Visible = True
End If
```

This code runs as expected.  I confirm this by going to the Task Manager.  After this code completes, an Excel app is open, and there is no background process running Excel.

After the Excel macro terminates, I reach the following point in my Word code:

```
'close the research tool
ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

'if Excel was not already running, close it and releases the resource
If Not excelAlreadyRunning = True Then
    ExcelApp.Application.Quit
    Set ExcelApp = Nothing
End If
Exit Sub
```

When execution reaches the Set ExcelApp = Nothing statement, the Excel application is gone from the Task Manager, but I now have a background process running Excel, whereas I had none before.  Again I confirm this through the Task Manager. This running background process causes problems the next time I run my Word macro because it detects an already running Excel application, whereas there should be none.

The question is – why is this happening, and how do I fix it?  I thought perhaps there might be an open UserForm leftover from my Excel macro, but I can find no evidence of that.  At this point, the only solution I see is to capture the open Excel PID and close it that way.  I would rather not do that at the risk of causing other issues.

Comment: Can you share your excel macro code?

Comment: Going to go out on a limb, as this used to be an issue with some Outlook macros I had... everything was tied to "this session" of Outlook, and the Excel loaded application processes did not terminate until I closed Outlook.  It may be similar to your Word situation... Have you verified if the process terminates when Word is closed?

Comment: Try using just `ExcelApp.Quit`

Comment: have you tried cleaning up Excel interop objects?  Just before your Exit Sub add `Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExcelApp)`

Comment: When you run a new Excel process, you need to call .Quit on it when you're done with it.

Comment: Based on the suggestion of Cyril, I closed my Word document when the macro finished executing.  That caused the Excel background process to go away.  I am going to pursue using taskkill to kill the process without having to close my Word document. Thanks to all who furnished feedback.